# Firebase auth persistent login in pwa

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-authentication, nuxt.js, progressive-web-apps

I am trying to integrate firebase auth in my nuxt pwa for offline use. But while running the app in offline mode it fails with a failed response from `www.googleapis.com/getAccountInfo?key=...` and `securetoken.googleapis.com/token?key=....`.
Isn't it suppose to cache that as well? Or is there any workaround for it.

[image: Here is the error.]

Config in nuxt.config.js

```
services: {
          auth: {
            static:true,
            persistence: 'local',
            initialize: {
              onAuthStateChangedMutation: 'ON_AUTH_STATE_CHANGED_MUTATION'
            }
          },
          firestore: {
            static:true
          },
        },
```

[Updated error screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VDBcK.png)

Answer (score 1):

When loading the page/app:

1. Firebase restores the authentication state from local persistence.
2. It then tries to verify that the authenticate state is still valid by calling the server.
3. If that call succeeds, it updates the local state.
4. If the call to the server could not be completed, it assumes the local state is still correct, at least until it can verify it.

So the call you're seeing is normal/expected, and should not interfere with the functioning of the application while it's offline.

Comment: Yes,it worked the same way as you pointed out in my flutter app, but here it keeps waiting and waiting and doesn't render my homepage. As soon as i reload it online it works, could it be my implementation issue?

Comment: I updated the error screenshot, hope it helps in any way

Comment: Can you reproduce that behavior in pure client-side code, with just the regular [JavaScript SDK](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/start)? The PWA part if fine, but I'm not sure how Nuxt.js affect thigns, so would recommend ruling that out first.

Comment: ok, after going through some documentation, i found that i needed to register firebase-auth-sw service worker inside pwa configuration in nuxt.config.js. After doing that i got this  "A ServiceWorker passed a promise to FetchEvent.respondWith() that rejected with ‘TypeError: NetworkError when attempting to fetch resource.’." thing and "Uncaught (in promise)" error. I'll see if i can catch that error. Will try with your way as well, thanks.

Comment: Good to hear you made progress. It might be worth posting your solution as a self-answer, so that others can benefit from it.

Comment: That's not a problem. A useful answer is a useful answer, no matter how many questions someone has posted before. :)